# Decrease picturebox width from left to right making HP bar for RPG game

Tags: vba, visual-studio, picturebox

i want to create 2 HP bar(left/right) using visual basic, i used

```
hp1.width -=10
```

to decrease left sided hp like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Ftv.png)
but when i used it to the right sided it becomes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MKGX.png)
i used

```
hp2.Left += 10
hp2.Width -= 10
```

for the right sided 
how to make the right sided hp bar decreased from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

```
    dim hp as integer = 0
    hp += 10
    '189 for width, 22 for height
    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(hp, 0, 189, 22)
    Dim bit As Bitmap = New Bitmap(My.Resources.HPBar_Right, 189, 22)
    Dim cropBitmap = New Bitmap(189, 22)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap)
    g.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    hp2.Image = cropBitmap
    hp2.Left += 10
    hp2.Refresh()
```